# How do I stop a link from changing the position on the page (maintain scroll back position)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an href tag with an image nested inside it and I want to be able stop the page jumping back to the top after it is clicked.

NOTE:

the href does not post back it fires a jQuery event on the page.

```
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:SendPlaylist()" style="border:none;"  class="addButton" ><img style="border:none;" src="/Images/icons/icon_add.gif"/></a>
```

Okay any help much appreciated.

Cheers,
Pete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just remove the anchor and add the onclick event to the image

like this:

```
<img style="border:none;cursor:pointer;" src="/Images/icons/icon_add.gif" onclick="javascript:SendPlaylist()"/>
```

Comment: +1 but you need to add some CSS too ( `cursor:pointer` on the img for example :) )

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
$(".addButton").click(function(event) {
    // Do your stuff here
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 3):

the logical solution here would be:

```
<a href="#" onclick="SendPlaylist(); return false;" style="border:none;"  class="addButton" ><img style="border:none;" src="/Images/icons/icon_add" onclick="javascript:SendPlaylist()"/></a>
```

you don't use the "javascript" keyword when using onclick... you can use it in the HREF itself, which would produce:

```
<a href="javascript:SendPlaylist(); return false;">
```

... and then you can remove the onclick part completely.

I also don't see a reason for another onclick for that img tag though - it can be removed altogether, since it would probably duplicate the call from that link

also, since you're saying that the link does not post back but uses a jQuery event, perhaps adding a "return false" to that event would work just as well as returning false in the onclick

Answer (score 1):

The href="#" causes it to jump to the top, so logically speaking, in order to prevent that type of behavior, you should replace the 'a' tag with a span or something similar.  The onclick should still work and unless SendPlaylist jumps to the top, it shouldn't change your scroll position.

Answer (score 1):

Jumping between links on a page using anchors and more or less staying with the link in question see anyword2

```
<html>
<body>

<a href="#top">top</a>

<a href="#anylink">Jump to anylink</a>

<a name="anylink">TEXT</a>


<p> Top

<a href="#anylink2">Jump to anylink2</a>


<br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br>

<p> bottom



<a href="#bottom">Jump to Bottom</a>


<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>

<a href="#anylink2">Stay at link2</a>
<a name="anylink2">anylink 2 </a>
<a href="#bottom">Jump to Bottom</a>


<br><br><br><br><br<br><br<br><br

<br><br><br><br><br<br><br<br><br<br<br><br

<a name="bottom">You're at the bottom!</A>

<a href="#top">Jump to top</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The OP is trying to *prevent* this from happening, not to make it happen.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the browser moves to the top, is that it attempts to find the anchor named "#".

You can remove the link tag altogether. Any element's onclick handler should be sufficient for your needs.